# Chi-square code's order

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, physics, chi-squared

I wrote a code for chi square. it is correct but there is a problem.
In the final lines we can see `c=c+chi` denoting sigma as a summation function.
The problem is, `c=c+chi` add previous terms of `o_m` to next one. We must have one `c` for `o_m=20`, one `c` for `o_m=21` ,one `c` for `o_m=22` and so on. but using `c=c+chi` at the final line of code we have
 c of `o_m=20`, c of `o_m=21` and `22`, c of o_m=21 and `22` and `23`  and so on.
In other words if our out put for each `o_m` must be around 560, 565, 571, 574, ..., this problem turns our outputs into
560, 1048, 1563, 2073 ,...
`c=c+chi` must sum just all of `z` originated from data file for each `o_m`.

what is wrong with my code's order?

I appreciate your help and your attention

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
min=l=a=b=chi=None
c=0
z,mo,err=np.genfromtxt('Union2.1_z_dm_err.txt',unpack=True)
def ant(z,o_m):            #0.01*o_m  is steps of o_m
    return 1/sqrt(((1+z)**2*(1+0.01*o_m*z)-z*(2+z)*(1-0.01*o_m)))
for o_m in range(20,40):
  for i in range(len(z)):
    q=quad(ant,0,z[i],args=(o_m,))[0]     #Integration o to z
    h=5*log10((1+z[i])*(299000/70)*q)+25     #function of dL
    chi=(mo[i]-h)**2/err[i]**2               #chi^2 test function
    c=c+chi
    l=o_m
print('chi^2=',c,'Om=',0.01*l,'OD=',1-0.01*l)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it in the code

```
for o_m in range(20,40): 
     c = 0
     for i in range(len(z)):
```